# Electron MacOS Ventura M1 mediaDevices.getUserMedia takes long time

Tags: electron, apple-m1, getusermedia, macos-ventura

**Problem:**

I have an electron app that uses the camera.
The app already exists for a few years with no issues on this side but lately, I have had a new issue specific to Mac M1 running MacOS Ventura. It takes a long time for the camera to load (around 8-10 seconds) and sometimes it even fails to do so.

```
NotReadableError: Failed to allocate videosource
```

**Stack:**

Electron: 15.5.4
Electron builder: 23.1.0
MacOS: 12.6
Intel processor

**My code:**

In order to present the camera I'm using the following code:

```
const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: { width: 800, height: 600 }
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((mediaStream) => {
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      video.play();
    };
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // always check for errors at the end.
    console.error(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
  });
```

And to create the browserWindow:

```
// Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        },
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
        })
    );
```

So far conclusions:

When I build my app on M1 it works flawlessly but I do want to keep building it on x86 machine and with x64 arch.

Building an arm64 arch on x86 machine doesn't solve this issue.

I made an app with camera only and it still happen.